# IndexError Cuando quiero analizar valores anteriores y posteriores de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Quiero comparar valores de una lista donde si lista[i], su anterior y posterior son 0, es decir

```
n = 0
lista = [1,0,0,0,1]
for i in lista:
    if lista[i] == 0 and lista[i-1] == 0 and lista[i+1] == 0:
        lista[i] = 1
        n += 1
```

Cuando un valor que sea 0 y esta entre dos 0s lo sustituya por 1 pero al llegar al final `i=4` y hace la suma i+1 no existe un elemento 5 y me devuelve este error.

Querría saber como evitar esto

**EDIT:**

si pongo `range(len(lista))` en el bucle, para este codigo funciona bien, pero si lo quieres extender para que [0,0,1] = [1,0,1] o [1,0,0] = [1,0,1] el codigo quedaria así:

```
n = 0
lista = [1,0,0,0,1]
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if (lista[i] == 0 and lista[i-1] == 0 and lista[i+1] == 0) or (i == 0 and lista[i] == 0 and lista[i+1] == 0) or (i == len(lista)-1 and lista[i] == 0 and lista[i-1] == 0):
        lista[i] = 1
        n += 1
```

Estos dos últimos `or` me dan problemas con el IndexError incluso con el `range(len(lista))`

Comment: Hola @Agente 156 en un bucle si rompes el indice que seria la variable **i** cuando le sumas un indice mas i este fuera del rango del array siempre se te rompera porque no lo encuentra. Por lo tanto tienes que que hacer que sume siempre y cuando haya elementos tendras que hacer un **count** o un **length** del array.

Comment: No veo donde estes sumando 1 a `i` además al iterar en la lista no obtienes las posiciones (osea 0, 1, 2...) sino que obtienes el contenido de la lista (1, 0, 0, 0, 1) hay una gran diferencia entre iterar en la lista (lo que tu estás haciendo) con iterar en el rango de la lista (que sería hacer `for i in range(len(lista))`

Answer (score 0):

Un problema es que

```
for i in lista:
```

te devuelve los elementos de `lista`, no los indices, por lo que `lista[i]` no tiene sentido.

Por otra parte, para evitar los indices fuera de rango, debes empezar y terminar el `for` a distancia segura de los bordes.

En este caso, recorremos `lista` desde el segundo elemento hasta el penúltimo. Así aseguramos que siempre exista el elemento anterior y el siguiente.

Luego es cosa de ir preguntando si se cumple la condición de tres elementos en cero y cambiar el de enmedio.

```
lista = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

print(lista)
for i in range(1, len(lista) - 1):
    if lista[i- 1] == 0 and lista[i] == 0 and lista[i + 1] == 0:
        lista[i] = 1
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```